# Make an SVG linearGradient follow the path

Tags: d3.js, svg, colors, path, gradient

I have a map of a circuitous route through the U.S. from Maine to San Diego (generated using a Travelling Salesman algorithm for each county), and I want to color it from red to blue indicating how far along the path has progressed, like so:

[image]

The above was generated by drawing 3,000 segments, one for each path between counties, and using a simple color scale to determine the color, using a 9-point ColorBrewer spectral scale:

```
var colors = ["#D53E4F", "#F46D43", "#FDAE61", "#FEE08B", "#FFFFBF", "#E6F598", "#ABDDA4", "#66C2A5", "#3288BD"];
var markers = d3.range(0, route.length, Math.floor(route.length / (colors.length - 1)));
var color_scale = d3.scaleLinear().range(colors).domain(markers);
```

But it would be MUCH more performant to make one long path out of every stop on the route. But when I make a `linearGradient` with 9 stops to color this line, it does not look correct:

[image]

```
var defs = svg.append("defs");

var gradient = defs.append("linearGradient")
   .attr("id", "svgGradient")
   .attr("x1", "0%")
   .attr("x2", "100%")
   .attr("y1", "0%")
   .attr("y2", "100%");

var interval = 12.5;

colors.reverse().forEach((d, i) => {
    gradient.append("stop")
       .attr('class', 'start')
       .attr("offset", i * interval + "%")
       .attr("stop-color", d)
       .attr("stop-opacity", 1);        
});
```

It's pretty obvious that the gradient is just applied to the path the same way it would a `rect`, with the first color in the upper left down to the last color in the lower right. I need the color to be calculated based on the point along the path, not the position on the map.

Somehow, [this example](https://www.freshconsulting.com/d3-js-gradients-the-easy-way/) seems to do what I need, but it may just be the nature of the sample making it appear that way. I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4163057) that recommends sampling the path at regular intervals, but I believe that just gets me back to where I started.

The original solution isn't terrible, but it's very heavy on the processor compared to a single path, particular on mobile phone.

Can gradients follow a path from start to finish, such that the `stop` refers to the progress along the path?

Comment: The example you linked is just a linear gradient. What you want is not possible. Just do as you had done, with separate segments. Have a look here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4163057

Comment: This seems like something you should do in canvas rather than SVG.

Comment: Thanks much. SVG vs. Canvas is always a hard decision, but this was far easier to pull off in D3. I ended up optimizing for mobile but skipping ahead to every 10th stop.
http://time.com/5072619/santa-tracker-christmas-eve/

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of hacking gradients along a path using variable stroke dash arrays and a filter, but it's only practical for relatively short segments (and arguably not all that practical for even those.) For a path this long, you'll need to use separate path segments & color them separately.